# Why does my smoke appear as a cube in render

Tags: rendering, particles, smoke-simulation

In *Solid* view its ok but in render view it displays as a cube. The same thing happens in both EEVEE and Cycles

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think once again i figured it out. its the emission strength.

Comment: an domain resolution in case of a smoke sim

Answer (score 0):

yes, add the shader on domain and reduce emission strength. if you use quick smoke it will be there already.

[image]